# Do anaconda packages interfere with system python

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I have a system with certain python version and packages installed suing the distribution repositories. For some project (calculation) I need newer version the the packages. I am thinking of installing anaconda and use conda virtual environments. Will this broke programs that must use the system packages?

(note: I tried virtual enviroment, but I couldn't install a newver version of matplotlib, because of problems with pygtk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this will not break your system's python. As long as you don't tick the option "register miniconda as the default system python" (or whatever that option is called depending on your OS).

One of the key benefits of conda is that you can create isolated python environments, fully independent of each other.

Comment: actually I am experience that since I installed anaconda, now whenever I activate another venv created previously with virtualenv, is been activate the anaconda base one instead of the one that should. Indeed I have Python 3.6 from anaconda, instead of the 3.5, as confirmation python refer to aanaconda as well as. This is happening being in the /bin folder of the specific venv

Comment: I also tried to install it in a venv created in order to not install in my home, but even once the venv is activated, try to install in the home. I will do more research but I guess a solution would be go for docker

Comment: To clarify, no anaconda  do not interfer with python system, but the coesistence with virtualenv is quite difficult, they do not play well, as from here as well http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/